# Confluent Cloud - Spring Boot Consumer REST Endpoint?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am trying to build a Java Spring Boot application that would post & get the messages from Confluent Cloud Kafka.

I followed the [article](https://seroter.com/2019/10/01/messing-around-with-apache-kafka-using-the-confluent-cloud-free-trial/) for publishing a Kafka message into Confluent Cloud and it works.

Below is the implementation

**KafkaController.java**

```
package com.seroter.confluentboot.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.seroter.confluentboot.dto.Product;
import com.seroter.confluentboot.engine.Producer;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/kafka")
public class KafkaController {

    private final Producer producer;
    
    private final com.seroter.confluentboot.engine.Consumer consumer;

    @Autowired
    KafkaController(Producer producer,com.seroter.confluentboot.engine.Consumer consumer) {
        this.producer = producer;
        this.consumer=consumer;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/publish")
    public void sendMessageToKafkaTopic(@RequestParam("message") String message) {
        this.producer.sendMessage(message);
    }
   
    
    @PostMapping(value="/publishJson")
    public ResponseEntity<Product> publishJsonMessage(@RequestBody Product product) {
        producer.sendJsonMessage(product);
        ResponseEntity<Product> responseEntity=new ResponseEntity<>(product,HttpStatus.CREATED);
        return responseEntity;
    }
    
    
}
```

**Product.java**

```
package com.seroter.confluentboot.dto;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonPropertyOrder(value = {"product_id","product_name","quantity","price"})
public class Product {

    @JsonProperty(value = "product_id")
    private int productId;
    @JsonProperty(value="product_name")
    private String productName;
    
    private int quantity;
    
    private double price;
    
}
```

**Producer.java**

```
package com.seroter.confluentboot.engine;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.seroter.confluentboot.dto.Product;

@Service
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class Producer {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Producer.class);
    private static final String TOPIC = "users";

    @Autowired
    private Source source;

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        logger.info(String.format("#### -> Producing message -> %s", message));
        this.source.output().send(new GenericMessage<>(message));
    }
    
    
    public void sendJsonMessage(Product product)
    {
        logger.info(String.format("#### -> Producing message -> %s",product.toString()));
        this.source.output().send(new GenericMessage<>(product));
    }
    
}
```

**ConfluentBootApplication.java**

```
package com.seroter.confluentboot;

import org.apache.tomcat.util.net.WriteBuffer.Sink;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.seroter.confluentboot.dto.Product;


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/confluent")

public class ConfluentBootApplication {
    @Autowired
    private  com.seroter.confluentboot.engine.Consumer consumer;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfluentBootApplication.class, args);
    }
    
     
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=pkc-epwny.eastus.azure.confluent.cloud:9092
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=test
  
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="user" password="password";
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.security.protocol=SASL_SSL

server.port=9000
```

It works

[image]

and I could verify

[image]

I want to build a Spring Boot Consumer REST Endpoint? How do I do it?

**Update:**

**ConfluentConsumer.java**

```
package com.seroter.confluentboot.controller;

import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Sink;

import com.seroter.confluentboot.dto.Product;

//@RestController
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class ConfluentConsumer {
    
    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void consumeMessage(Product product)
    {
        System.out.println("******************************");
        System.out.println("============= "+product.getProductId()+" ================");
        System.out.println("******************************");
    }

}
```

**Consumer.java**

```
package com.seroter.confluentboot.engine;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class Consumer {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Producer.class);
}
```

Comment: It might help if you edit your question to include what you expect to happen. For example, a topic has thousands of messages. Do you get them all, just the latest, or the first? If you get more than one message - are you expecting them to be serialized into a list? When you get multiple messages, and you would make the same request, is the consumer committing the offsets and therefore you'd get different messages? Kinda what I'm getting at is that Kafka really isn't designed for this type of access pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do here is, pick the latest message from `Kafka consumer` via a `REST` endpoint i.e. you want manually poll the `Kafka` topic. Publishing a message via a `REST` endpoint is logical, but consuming messages through an endpoint doesn't sound like a good idea. If you want a queue behavior, you should use `RabbitMQ` instead of `Kafka`.

But still, if you want to use `Kafka` and poll the message manually. You can use one of the below 2 approaches.

**Approach 1:** Create a `ConsumerFactory` and get a `Consumer` from the factory, and then poll Kafka using a `Consumer`

```
@Configuration
class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    private static final String TOPIC_NAME = "test";
    private final String userName = "username";
    private final String password = "password";

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"pkc-epwny.eastus.azure.confluent.cloud:9092");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,"conumer-gp-1");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SASL_SSL");
        props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, "PLAIN");

        props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=" + userName + " password=" + password);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<String, String> createConsumer(ConsumerFactory consumerFactory) {
        Consumer consumer = consumerFactory.createConsumer("consumer-group-1", "client-1");
        consumer.subscribe(List.of(TOPIC_NAME));
        return consumer;
    }
}
```

You can read the topic name, group-id, bootstrap servers, SSL configs, etc. from the application.properties

Now you can consume messages by injecting the consumer in the RestController.

```
private final Consumer<String, String> consumer;

@Autowired
ConsumerController(Consumer<String, String> consumer) {
    this.consumer = consumer;
}

@GetMapping("retrieveMessage")
public String getMessage() {
    // Kafka might return more than 1 events so be careful
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(1000));
    if (!consumerRecords.isEmpty()) {
        Iterator<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> iterator = consumerRecords.iterator();
        String value = iterator.next().value();
        consumer.commitSync();
        return value;
    } else {
        return "no message";
    }
}
```

**Approach 2:** store the messages in an in-memory queue and then poll the in-memory queue

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=test
```

Then store the messages in a `Queue` and retrieve it via `REST` endpoint

```
@RestController
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
class ConsumerController {

    private final Queue<String> queue;

    ConsumerController() {
        this.queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    }


    @StreamListener(target = Sink.INPUT)
    public void consume(String message) {
        this.queue.add(message);
    }

    @GetMapping("getMessage")
    public String retrieveMessage() {
        return this.queue.poll();
    }
}
```

**Cons:** you'll lose all the in-memory messages if your application restarts. Thus, storing the messages in a distributed cache such as `Redis` would be a better solution.